# How do I create Video object statically on stage?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, flash-cs4

Needless to say I am a beginner in Flash. I want to add Video Object to my stage. How do I do that? In my components window the closes component I see is FLVPlayback. I want to show my webcam. Well my stage has an instance of FLVPlayback and I named it video.

I then try to show webcam using:

```
cam = Camera.getCamera();
            if(cam != null)
            {
                cam.setQuality(144000, 85);
                cam.setMode(320, 240, 15);
                cam.setKeyFrameInterval(60);

                video.attachCamera(cam);


            }
```

in a button click but I get this error:

```
1061: Call to a possibly undefined method attachCamera through a reference with static type fl.video:FLVPlayback.
```

Note: All the examples on the web dynamically create Video. It works that way but how I want to create my video object on stage only and position it properly. I don't want to create it at runtime using new.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your error message, "video" is an instance of [FLVPlayback](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/fl/video/FLVPlayback.html), which, according to the documentation, wraps a [VideoPlayer](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/fl/video/VideoPlayer.html) object. It looks like FLVPlayback provides most of the same methods as VideoPlayer, which is why you got the two confused, but one method FLVPlayback does *not* provide is attachCamera().

Try this instead:

```
video.getVideoPlayer(video.activeVideoPlayerIndex).attachCamera(cam);
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the FLVPlayback object from stage and get rid of it completly so it doesnt block the name video anymore.

Then change your code like this:

```
import flash.media.video; //here you get the right video class from flash library



var video = new Video(); // this will work after the import is done
cam = Camera.getCamera();

if(cam != null)
{
   cam.setQuality(144000, 85);
   cam.setMode(320, 240, 15);
   cam.setKeyFrameInterval(60);

   video.attachCamera(cam); 

    addChild(video) // brings video object to stage so its visible
}
```

You took the wrong component, but you want to create an Video instance first and then attach the cam to it... mostly right what you did

Comment: Hi Thanks, but didn't I mention I don't want to create Video object using new? Please see player_03's answer.